# Text area event not working - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with text area with jQuery. Please refer the following HTML.

```
<div class="CodeMirror">
    <div>
        <textarea autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" wrap="off">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

the above text area doesn't have id,so with the help of jQuery i added it .

```
$('.CodeMirror').children().find('textarea').attr('id','new_editor');
```

i inspected through firebug and i can see "new_editor" as the id of that text area.
But the problem is i cant attach any event/get values on that text area with id new_editor.

i also tried

```
$("#new_editor").live('click',function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

But not working ....that text area is dynamically generated by CodeMirror (codemirror.net).

Now i want to do some operation on that text area by using jQuery.

whats wrong with me ?? please help
Thank you.

EDIT - Sorry,its not the problem actually that was a mistake [typing mistake,my real code is with # and not with $ sign]

Comment: Why do you need to use `live` on an existing element?

Comment: You don't have to select children before calling `find`. `$(".CodeMirror").find("textarea")` works fine

Comment: we need more information on the problem. see http://jsfiddle.net/ssyuS/ this works, but what is different with your code?

Comment: here,we are putting the codemirror div by default,but in my code it is automatically rendering,

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong selector. 
Try this. (# instead $)

```
$("#new_editor").live('click',function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: EDIT - Sorry,its not the problem actually that was a mistake [typing mistake,my real code is with # and not with $ sign]

Answer (score 1):

That's because your selector is wrong. Switch `$` with `#` in your selector:

```
$("#new_editor")....
```

Comment: EDIT - Sorry,its not the problem actually that was a mistake [typing mistake,my real code is with # and not with $ sign]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i pasted it into JSFIDDLE here http://jsfiddle.net/j7W7U/2/

And it seems to be working perfect... So make sure you don't have an error somewhere else, and check your console for errors :)

---

$("$new_editor").live('click',function(){
    alert('test');
    });

should be

```
$("#new_editor").live('click',function(){
alert('test');
});
```

You mistyped $ with # :)

Comment: EDIT - Sorry,its not the problem actually that was a mistake [typing mistake,my real code is with # and not with $ sign]

Comment: Not working ,i integrated http://codemirror.net/ plugin ,i think that it is preventing me...